# How to change style for multiple views in Sharepoint 2019 on premise using Powershell

Tags: powershell, sharepoint

I am running the following to get all views for all lists in all subsites of our Sharepoint installation.

```bsh
$views = @()
foreach ($web in Get-PnPSubWebs) {
    foreach ($list in Get-PnPList -Web $web.id) {
        foreach ($view in Get-PnPView -list $list.id -web $web.id) {
            $views += [pscustomobject]@{Id = $view.Id; StyleId = $view.StyleId}
        }
    }
}
```

Which works fine, I am getting all views as expected. But I have not been successful in setting a new style for the views.

I have tried to use `$view.ApplyStyle()` as is described here: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/sharepoint/en-US/58068fb4-33ad-46cf-b866-bd86e1cbcafb/update-sharepoint-list-view-style-via-powershell and here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.spview.applystyle.aspx.
I however get the following error:
`Method invocation failed because [Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.View] does not contain a method named 'ApplyStyle'.`

Next I tried `Set-PnPView -Web $web.id -List $list.id -Identity $view.Id -Values @{StyleId=17}` per these instructions: 
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/sharepoint-pnp/set-pnpview?view=sharepoint-ps. That only got me this message:
`WARNING: Setting property 'StyleId' to '17' failed with exception 'Property set method not found.'. Value will be ignored.`

And as a last resort `$view.StyleId = 17` does also not work. Then I get this: `'StyleId' is a ReadOnly property.` as expected.

We want to have our lists all be in the shaded style (id:17). We have hundreds of lists and since I'm hoping there is a better way then spending a full day manually changing them all. I have yet to find a way to change the default list view style but all our lists seem to be set to "default" view although there isn't a way to see what the default style is or change it.

All suggestions appreciated.

---

Update: 
This is the complete script that I ended up using for all views in all lists in all subwebs of our main site:

```
Connect-PnPOnline –Url http://sharepointsite –CurrentCredentials
foreach ($web in Get-PnPSubWebs) {
    foreach ($list in Get-PnPList -Web $web.id) {
        foreach ($view in Get-PnPView -list $list.id -web $web.id) {
            [xml]$Doc = New-Object System.Xml.XmlDocument
            $Doc.LoadXml($view.ListViewXml);
            $element = $Doc.SelectSingleNode("//View//ViewStyle");
            if ($element -eq $null)
            {
                $element = $Doc.CreateElement("ViewStyle");
                $element.SetAttribute("ID", 17);
                $Doc.DocumentElement.AppendChild($element);
            }
            else
            {
                $element.SetAttribute("ID", 17);
            }
            Set-PnPView -Web $web.id -List $list.id -Identity $view.Id -Values @{ListViewXml=$Doc.FirstChild.InnerXml}
        }
    }
}
```

And then to get all lists for out main web as well I ran this:

```
Connect-PnPOnline –Url http://sharepointsite –CurrentCredentials
$web = Get-PnPWeb
foreach ($list in Get-PnPList -Web $web.id) {
    foreach ($view in Get-PnPView -list $list.id -web $web.id) {
        [xml]$Doc = New-Object System.Xml.XmlDocument
        $Doc.LoadXml($view.ListViewXml);
        $element = $Doc.SelectSingleNode("//View//ViewStyle");
        if ($element -eq $null)
        {
            $element = $Doc.CreateElement("ViewStyle");
            $element.SetAttribute("ID", 17);
            $Doc.DocumentElement.AppendChild($element);
        }
        else
        {
            $element.SetAttribute("ID", 17);
        }
        Set-PnPView -Web $web.id -List $list.id -Identity $view.Id -Values @{ListViewXml=$Doc.FirstChild.InnerXml}
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is my sample test script for your reference(I tested in online, I think it should works for SharePoint 2019 as it's CSOM api).

```
Add-Type -Path (Resolve-Path "C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Web Server Extensions\16\ISAPI\Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.dll")
Add-Type -Path (Resolve-Path "C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Web Server Extensions\16\ISAPI\Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.Runtime.dll")
$UserName = "Wendy@tenant.onmicrosoft.com" 
$siteURL = "https://tenant.sharepoint.com/sites/lee"
$Password = "password"
[SecureString]$SecurePass = ConvertTo-SecureString $Password -AsPlainText -Force
$Credentials = New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.SharePointOnlineCredentials($Username, $SecurePass)
$ctx = New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ClientContext($siteURL)  
$ctx.credentials = $Credentials  
try{  
    $list = $ctx.web.Lists.GetByTitle("MyList2")  
    $views = $list.views  
    $ctx.load($views)  
    $ctx.executeQuery()  
    foreach ($v in $views)
            {
                if ($v.Title -eq "All Items")
                {

                    $ctx.Load($v);
                    $ctx.ExecuteQuery();
                    [xml]$Doc = New-Object System.Xml.XmlDocument
                    $Doc.LoadXml($v.ListViewXml);
                    $element = $Doc.SelectSingleNode("//View//ViewStyle");
                    if ($element -eq $null)
                    {
                        $element = $Doc.CreateElement("ViewStyle");
                        $element.SetAttribute("ID", 17);
                        $Doc.DocumentElement.AppendChild($element);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        $element.SetAttribute("ID", 17);
                    }

                    $v.ListViewXml = $Doc.FirstChild.InnerXml;
                    $v.Update();                      
                    $ctx.ExecuteQuery();                    
                }
            }  
}  
catch{  
    write-host "$($_.Exception.Message)" -foregroundcolor red  
}
```